# Is this a decent use-case for goto in C?

Tags: c, design-patterns, goto

I really hesitate to ask this, because I don't want to "solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion" but I'm new to C and want to gain more insight into common patterns used in the language.

I recently heard some distaste for the `goto` command, but I've also recently found a decent use-case for it.

Code like this:

```
error = function_that_could_fail_1();
if (!error) {
    error = function_that_could_fail_2();
    if (!error) {
        error = function_that_could_fail_3();
        ...to the n-th tab level!
    } else {
        // deal with error, clean up, and return error code
    }
} else {
    // deal with error, clean up, and return error code
}
```

If the clean-up part is all very similar, could be written a little prettier (my opinion?) like this:

```
error = function_that_could_fail_1();
if(error) {
    goto cleanup;
}
error = function_that_could_fail_2();
if(error) {
    goto cleanup;
}
error = function_that_could_fail_3();
if(error) {
    goto cleanup;
}
...
cleanup:
// deal with error if it exists, clean up
// return error code
```

Is this a common or acceptable use-case of `goto` in C? Is there a different/better way to do this?

Comment: See also [this question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/566/33478) (and [my answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/133523/33478)).

Comment: That's probably the one excuse for *goto*, of course if you really object you can use c++ and exceptions - but that's just goto with a sugar coating

Comment: @DeadMG You'd still end up with lots of nesting.

Comment: @Izkata: Of what, implicitly called destructors? Yeah, I totally have that problem of having to nest calls to them.

Comment: More than sugar coating, the compiler guarantees cleanup and error checking, whereas in C you must do it manually, violating DRY and guaranteeing that in some place you were too lazy to check the error code or went to the wrong label or something like that.

Comment: @DeadMG Pseudocode: `try { [some code 1] try { [some code 2] ''To the n-th tab level!'' } except { [cleanup code 2] } } except { [cleanup code 1] }`.  And don't argue about abstracting it out into other objects/functions, the same could be done with return codes.

Comment: @Izkata: No, the point is to have functions (like destructors) which are *implicitly* called by the compiler when an exception is thrown.

Comment: @DeadMG: Using another language is not always an option.

Comment: I think with appropriate label naming, example may look quite decent: `goto hell;`

Comment: Why nest all the conditionals?  Just write a series of `if(!error) { error = possibly_fail_x(...); }`.  If one of your functions returns an error, you'll just fall through the remaining `if` statements to your error handling code.  The cost to evaluate `!error` boils down to executing some variant of a compare-and-branch instruction on an operand which is already in the D-cache (and possibly in a register) -- not free, but nearly.

Comment: @TMN It's when you've got loops as well that things get truly messy. Of course, that's also when it's time to think in terms of refactoring so that you can `return` instead…

Comment: The `cleanup` tag could be done better with fail3 going to cleanup3, and fail2 going to cleanup2, and fail1 going to cleanup1.  Then have `fail3: cleanup from 3; fail2: cleanup from 2; fail1: cleanup from 1;`  - this may make a better case for the goto error handling (as described by Izkata below).

Comment: see also: [Approaches to checking multiple conditions?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/191208/31260)

Comment: In a situation like this, usually the best solution is to split the code in 2 functions. One function would call all the `function_that_could_fail_#` and immediately return the error code on an error (nested if could be used if the nesting is less than about 3 levels).

Comment: Also testing the error code each time is not that bad if it is not easy to split the code in 2 functions. Impact on performance will be negligible particularly if errors are rare.

Comment: Just want to add a real-world example where goto is actually used, neovim, for example, [here](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/commit/95352f490a24f5e3a1cc788d297105e4eadf1481).

Comment: This looks similar to the famously buggy "goto fail" code from Apple. Not sure whether that shows it might be a good pattern because it was used by a successful company, or a bad pattern because it was involved in an expensive bug.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The `goto` statement (and its corresponding labels) are a flow control *primitive* (along with conditional execution of a statement). By that, I mean that they are there to allow you to construct program flow control networks. You can think of them as modeling the arrows between the nodes of a flowchart.

Some of these can be optimized out immediately, where there is a direct linear flow (you just use a sequence of basic statements). Other patterns are best replaced with structured programming constructs where these are available; if it looks like a `while` loop, *use a `while` loop*, OK? The structured programming patterns are definitely at least *potentially* clearer of intent than a mess of `goto` statements.

Yet C does not include all possible structured programming constructs. (It's not clear to me that all relevant ones have been discovered yet; the rate of discovery is slow now, but I'd hesitate to jump to saying that all have been found.) Of the ones we know about, C definitely lacks the `try`/`catch`/`finally` structure (and exceptions too). It also lacks multi-level `break`-from-loop. These are the kinds of things which a `goto` can be used to implement. It's possible to use other schemes to do these too — we do know that C has a *sufficient* set of non-`goto` primitives — but these often involve creating flag variables and much more complex loop or guard conditions; increasing the entanglement of the control analysis with the data analysis makes the program harder to understand overall. It also makes it more difficult for the compiler to optimize and for the CPU to execute rapidly (most flow control constructs — and *definitely* `goto` — are very cheap).

Thus, while you shouldn't use `goto` unless needed, you should be aware that it exists and that it *may* be needed, and if you need it, you shouldn't feel too bad. An example of a case where it is needed is resource deallocation when a called function returns an error condition. (That is, `try`/`finally`.) It's possible to write that without `goto` but doing that can have downsides of its own, such as the problems of maintaining it. An example of the case:

```
int frobnicateTheThings() {
    char *workingBuffer = malloc(...);
    int i;

    for (i=0 ; i<numberOfThings ; i++) {
        if (giveMeThing(i, workingBuffer) != OK)
            goto error;
        if (processThing(workingBuffer) != OK)
            goto error;
        if (dispatchThing(i, workingBuffer) != OK)
            goto error;
    }

    free(workingBuffer);
    return OK;

  error:
    free(workingBuffer);
    return OOPS;
}
```

The code could be even shorter, but it's enough to demonstrate the point.

Comment: +1: In C goto is technically never "needed" - there is always a way to do it, it gets messy..... For a robust set of guidelines for use of goto look at MISRA C.

Comment: Would you prefer `try/catch/finally` to `goto` in spite of the similar, yet more pervasive (as it can spread throughout multiple functions/modules) form of spaghetti code that's possible using `try/catch/finally`?

Answer (score 74):

Yes.

It is used in, for example, the linux kernel.  Here's an email from the end of a [thread from nearly a decade ago](https://lkml.org/lkml/2003/1/12/203), bolding mine:

> From: Robert Love
>   Subject: Re: any chance of 2.6.0-test*?
>   Date:     12 Jan 2003 17:58:06 -0500
>   
>   On Sun, 2003-01-12 at 17:22, Rob Wilkens wrote:
>
> > I say "please don't use goto" and instead have a "cleanup_lock" function
> >     and add that before all the return statements..  It should not be a
> >     burden.  Yes, it's asking the developer to work a little harder, but the
> >     end result is better code.
>
> No, it is gross and it **bloats the kernel**.  It inlines a bunch of junk
>   for N error paths, as opposed to having the exit code once at the end. 
>   **Cache footprint is key and you just killed it.**
>
> Nor is it easier to read.
>
> As a final argument, **it does not let us cleanly do the usual stack-esque
>   wind and unwind**, i.e.
>
> ```
>         do A
>         if (error)
>             goto out_a;
>         do B
>         if (error)
>             goto out_b;
>         do C
>         if (error)
>             goto out_c;
>         goto out;
>         out_c:
>         undo C
>         out_b:
>         undo B:
>         out_a:
>         undo A
>         out:
>         return ret;
> ```
>
> Now stop this.
>
> Robert Love

That said, it requires a lot of discipline to keep yourself from creating spaghetti code once you get used to using goto, so unless you're writing something that requires speed and a low memory footprint (like a kernel or embedded system) you should *really* think about it *before* you write the first goto.

Comment: Note that a kernel is different from a non-kernel program regarding the priority on raw speed versus readability.  In other words, they have _ALREADY_ profiled and found that they need to optimize their code for speed with goto.

Comment: Using stack un-wind to handle clean up on error without actually pushing onto the stack! This is an awesome use of goto.

Comment: @user1249, Rubbish, you can't profile every {past, existing, future} app that uses a piece of {library, kernel} code. **You simply need to be fast.**

Comment: Unrelated: I'm amazed how people can use mailing lists to get anything done, let alone such massive projects. It's just so... primitive. How do people come in with the firehouse of messages?!

Comment: @Alexander well the mailing lists doesn't work particularly well. Some people are afraid of asking questions because of getting shout at. People can be really abusive on the mailing list and nobody is stopping them, many potential kernel developers are turned away by this. Red Hat and other companies with a lot of software engineers are having their own kernel developers that use their own company infrastructure to coordinate and just at some point throw their stuff into the kernel git. An issue system like JIRA and a moderator would really help IMHO.

Comment: I'm not so concerned about the moderation. If somebody is soft enough to be turned away by some asshole on the internet, your project is probably better off without them. I'm more concerned about the impracticality of keeping up with the barrage of incoming messages, and how you could possibly have a natural back-forth discussion with so little tooling for keep track of quotes, for example.

Answer (score 14):

In my opinion, the code you posted is an example of a valid use of `goto`, because you only jump downwards and only use it like a primitive exception handler.

*However*, because of the old goto debate, programmers have been avoiding `goto` for some 40 years and therefore they aren't used to read code with goto. This is a valid reason to avoid goto: it simply isn't the standard.

I would have rewritten the code as something more easily read by C programmers:

```
Error some_func (void)
{
  Error error;
  type_t* resource = malloc(...);

  error = some_other_func (resource);

  free (resource);

  /* error handling can be placed here, or it can be returned to the caller */

  return error;
}


Error some_other_func (type_t* resource)  // inline if needed
{
  error = function_that_could_fail_1();
  if(error)
  {
    return error;
  }

  /* ... */

  error = function_that_could_fail_2();
  if(error)
  {
    return error;
  }

  /* ... */

  return ok;
}
```

Advantages of this design:

- The function doing the actual work does not need to concern itself with tasks that are irrelevant to its algorithm, such as allocating data.
- The code will look less alien to C programmers, since they are afraid of goto and labels.
- You can centralize error handling and deallocation at the same spot, outside the function doing the algorithm. It doesn't make sense for a function to handle its own results.

Answer (score 12):

A famous paper describing case of valid use of was [Structured Programming with GOTO Statement](http://sbel.wisc.edu/Courses/ME964/Literature/knuthProgramming1974.pdf) by Donald E. Knuth (Stanford University). The paper appeared in the days where using GOTO was considered a sin by some and when the movement for Structured Programming was the at its peak. You may want to take a look at [GoTo Considered Harmful.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486618/go-to-statement-considered-harmful)

Comment: Note that the proof that goto isn’t needed transformed programs in a way ten times worse than using goto. And the problem wasn’t goto, but languages like Fortran IV that required goto in situations where it was inappropriate.

Comment: @gnasher729, I fully agree. The cases is very evident in validation of large number of fields sequentially, and having to manually nest conditions and scroll left-and right instead of scrolling up and down :)

Answer (score 10):

I think it *is* a decent use case, but in case "error" is nothing more than a boolean value, there is a different way to accomplish what you want:

```
error = function_that_could_fail_1();
error = error || function_that_could_fail_2();
error = error || function_that_could_fail_3();
if(error)
{
     // do cleanup
}
```

This makes use of the short-circuit evaluation of boolean operators, which guarantees that after the first failing function the others are not executed any more. If this "better", is up to your personal taste and how much you are accustomed to that idiom.

Answer (score 9):

In Java you'd do it like this:

```
makeCalls:  {
    error = function_that_could_fail_1();
    if (error) {
        break makeCalls;
    }
    error = function_that_could_fail_2();
    if (error) {
        break makeCalls;
    }
    error = function_that_could_fail_3();
    if (error) {
        break makeCalls;
    }
    ...
    return 0;  // No error code.
}
// deal with error if it exists, clean up
// return error code
```

I use this a lot.  Much as I dislike `goto`'s, in most other C-style languages I use your code; there's no other good way to do it.  (Jumping out of nested loops is a similar case; in Java I use a labeled `break` and everywhere else I use a `goto`.)

Comment: Aw that's a neat control structure.

Comment: This also works in Javascript. I guess there is one thing where it is similar to Java after all.

Comment: This is really interesting. I would normally think of using try/catch/finally structure for this in java (throwing exceptions instead of breaking).

Comment: @Robz:  if the methods are as regular as in this example, and you can make them throw properly, try/catch/finally could actually work here _and_ be beautiful.  (Normally I find them awkward and ugly, even when they _are_ the best solution.)  But this kind of break works even when the conditions are complex, involved, and contrary.  It works when nothing else will, and looks good doing it.

Comment: That is really unreadable (at least for me). If present, exceptions are far better.

Comment: @m3th0dman I agree with you in this particular example (error handling). But there are other (non-exceptional) cases where this idiom could come in handy.

Comment: Exceptions are expensive, they need to generate an error, stacktrace and a lot more junk. This label break gives a clean exit from a checking loop. unless one doesn't care about memory and speed, then for all I care use an exception.

Comment: @m3th0dman Yes.  I'd like to at least some argument for why exceptions wouldn't be used instead.  They fit this situation perfectly and makes the code a lot less bloated.

Answer (score 8):

The linux style guide gives specific reasons to use `goto`'s which are in line with your example:

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/process/coding-style.rst

> The rationale for using gotos is:
>
> - unconditional statements are easier to understand and follow
> - nesting is reduced
> - errors by not updating individual exit points when making
>     modifications are prevented
> - saves the compiler work to optimize redundant code away ;)

**Disclaimer** I'm not supposed to share my work.  The examples here are a bit contrived so bear please bear with me.

This is good for memory management.  I recently worked on code that had dynamically allocated memory (for example a `char *` returned by a function).  A function that looks at a path and ascertains whether the path is valid by parsing the tokens of the path:

```
tmp_string = strdup(string);
token = strtok(tmp_string,delim);
while( token != NULL ){
    ...
    some statements, some involving dynamically allocated memory
    ...
    if ( check_this() ){
        free(var1);
        free(var2);
        ...
        free(varN);
        return 1;
    }
    ...
    some more stuff
    ...
    if(something()){
        if ( check_that() ){
            free(var1);
            free(var2);
            ...
            free(varN);
            return 1;
        } else {
            free(var1);
            free(var2);
            ...
            free(varN);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    token = strtok(NULL,delim);
}

free(var1);
free(var2);
...
free(varN);
return 1;
```

Now to me, the following code is much nicer and easier to maintain if you need to add a `varNplus1`:

```
int retval = 1;
tmp_string = strdup(string);
token = strtok(tmp_string,delim);
while( token != NULL ){
    ...
    some statements, some involving dynamically allocated memory
    ...
    if ( check_this() ){
        retval = 1;
        goto out_free;
    }
    ...
    some more stuff
    ...
    if(something()){
        if ( check_that() ){
            retval = 1;
            goto out_free;
        } else {
            retval = 0;
            goto out_free;
        }
    }
    token = strtok(NULL,delim);
}

out_free:
free(var1);
free(var2);
...
free(varN);
return retval;
```

Now the code had all sorts of other problems with it, namely that N was somewhere above 10, and the function was over 450 lines, with 10 levels of nestedness in some places.

But I offered my supervisor to refactor it, which I did and now it's a bunch of functions that are all short, and they all have the linux style

```
int function(const char * param)
{
    int retval = 1;
    char * var1 = fcn_that_returns_dynamically_allocated_string(param);
    if( var1 == NULL ){
        retval = 0;
        goto out;
    }

    if( isValid(var1) ){
         retval = some_function(var1);
         goto out_free;
    }

    if( isGood(var1) ){
         retval = 0;
         goto out_free;
    }

out_free:
    free(var1);
out:
    return retval;
}
```

If we consider the equivalent without `goto`s:

```
int function(const char * param)
{
    int retval = 1;
    char * var1 = fcn_that_returns_dynamically_allocated_string(param);
    if( var1 != NULL ){

       if( isValid(var1) ){
            retval = some_function(var1);
       } else {
          if( isGood(var1) ){
               retval = 0;
          }
       }
       free(var1);

    } else {
       retval = 0;
    }

    return retval;
}
```

To me, in the first case, it is obvious to me that if the first function returns `NULL`, we're outta here and we're returning `0`.  In the second case, I have to scroll down to see that the if contains the whole function.  Granted the first one indicates this to me stylistically (the name "`out`") and the second one does it syntactically.  The first one is still more obvious.

Also, I greatly prefer having `free()` statements at the end of a function.   That's partly because, in my experience, `free()` statements in the middle of functions smell bad and indicate to me that I should create a subroutine.  In this case, I created `var1` in my function and could not `free()` it in a subroutine, but that's why the `goto out_free`, goto out style is so practical.

I think programmers need to be brought up believing that `goto`'s are evil.  Then, when they're mature enough, they should browse the Linux source code and read the linux style guide.

I should add that I use this style very consistently, every function has an int `retval`, an `out_free` label and an out label.  Because of stylistic consistency, readability is improved.

**Bonus: Breaks and continues**

Say you have a while loop

```
char *var1, *var2;
char line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
while( sscanf(line,... ){
    var1 = functionA(line,count);
    var2 = functionB(line,count);

    if( functionC(var1, var2){
         count++
         continue;
    }

    ...
    a bunch of statements
    ...

    count++;
    free(var1);
    free(var2);
}
```

There are other things wrong with this code, but one thing is the continue statement.  I would like to rewrite the whole thing, but I was tasked with modifying it in a small way.  It would have taken me days to refactor it in a way that satisfied me, but the actual change was about a half day's work.  The problem is that even if we '`continue`' we still need to free `var1` and `var2`.  I had to add a `var3`, and it made me want to puke to have to mirror the free() statements.

I was a relatively new intern at the time, but I had been looking at the linux source code for fun a while back, so I asked my supervisor if I could use a goto statement.  He said yes, and I did this:

```
char *var1, *var2;
char line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
while( sscanf(line,... ){
    var1 = functionA(line,count);
    var2 = functionB(line,count);
    var3 = newFunction(line,count);

    if( functionC(var1, var2){
         goto next;
    }

    ...
    a bunch of statements
    ...
next:
    count++;
    free(var1);
    free(var2);
}
```

I think continues are OK at best but to me they're like a goto with an invisible label.  The same goes for breaks.  I would still prefer continue or break unless, as was the case here, it forces you to mirror modifications in multiple places.

And I should also add that this use of `goto next;` and the `next:` label are unsatisfactory to me.  They are merely better than mirroring the `free()`'s and the `count++` statements.

`goto`'s are almost always wrong, but one must know when they are good to use.

One thing that I didn't discuss is error handling which has been covered by other answers.

**Performance**

One can look at the implementation of strtok() http://opensource.apple.com//source/Libc/Libc-167/string.subproj/strtok.c

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>

char *
strtok(s, delim)
    register char *s;
    register const char *delim;
{
    register char *spanp;
    register int c, sc;
    char *tok;
    static char *last;


    if (s == NULL && (s = last) == NULL)
        return (NULL);

    /*
     * Skip (span) leading delimiters (s += strspn(s, delim), sort of).
     */
cont:
    c = *s++;
    for (spanp = (char *)delim; (sc = *spanp++) != 0;) {
        if (c == sc)
            goto cont;
    }

    if (c == 0) {       /* no non-delimiter characters */
        last = NULL;
        return (NULL);
    }
    tok = s - 1;

    /*
     * Scan token (scan for delimiters: s += strcspn(s, delim), sort of).
     * Note that delim must have one NUL; we stop if we see that, too.
     */
    for (;;) {
        c = *s++;
        spanp = (char *)delim;
        do {
            if ((sc = *spanp++) == c) {
                if (c == 0)
                    s = NULL;
                else
                    s[-1] = 0;
                last = s;
                return (tok);
            }
        } while (sc != 0);
    }
    /* NOTREACHED */
}
```

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe that the `cont:` label and the `goto cont;` statement are there for performance (they surely don't make the code more readable).  They could be replaced with readable code by doing

```
while( isDelim(*s++,delim));
```

to skip delimiters. But to be as fast as possible and avoid unnecessary function calls, they do it this way.

I read the paper by Dijkstra and I find it quite esoteric.

google "dijkstra goto statement considered harmful" because I don't have enough reputation to post more than 2 links.

I've seen it quoted as a reason not to use goto's and reading it has not changed anything as far as my uses of goto's are concered.

**Addendum**:

I've come up with a neat rule while thinking about all this about continues and breaks.

- If in a while loop, you have a continue, then the body of the while
  loop should be a function and the continue be a return statement.
- If in a while loop, you have a break statement, then the while loop
  itself should be a function and the break should become a return
  statement.
- If you have both, then something might be wrong.

It's not always possible due to scope issues but I've found that doing this make it much easier to reason about my code.  I had noticed that whenever a while loop had a break or a continue it gave me a bad feeling.

Comment: +1 but may I disagree on one point? "I think programmers need to be brought up believing that goto's are evil." Maybe so, but I first learned to program in BASIC, with line numbers and GOTOs, without a text editor, in 1975. I met structured programming ten years later, after which it took me one month to stop using GOTO on my own, without any pressure to stop. Today, I use GOTO a few times a year for various reasons, but it doesn't come up much. Not having been brought up to believe that GOTO is evil has done me no harm that I know, and it might even have done some good. That's just me.

Comment: I think you're right about that.  I was brought up with the idea that GOTOs were not to be used and by pure happenstance, I was browsing the Linux source code at a time when I was working on code that had these functions with multiple exit points with memory to free.  Otherwise, I would never have known about these techniques.

Comment: @thb Also, funny story, I asked my supervisor at the time, as an intern for permission to use GOTO's and I made sure that I explained to him that I was going to use them in a specific way like the way it's used in the Linux kernel and he said "Ok, that makes sense, and also, I didn't know you could use GOTO's in C".

Comment: @thb I don't know whether it is good to goto into loops (instead of breaking the loops) like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25797659/1190191)? Well, it is a bad example, but I find that the quicksort with goto statements (example 7a) on Knuth's [Structured Programming with go to Statements](http://www.kohala.com/start/papers.others/knuth.dec74.html) not very comprehensible.

Comment: @Yai0Phah I will explain my point but my explanation does not diminish your fine example 7a! I approve the example. Still, bossy sophomores like to lecture people about goto. It is hard to find a practical use of goto since 1985 that causes significant trouble, whereas one can find harmless gotos that ease the programmer's work. Goto so seldom arises in modern programming, anyway, that, when it does arise, my advice is, if you want to use it, then you should probably just use it. Goto is fine. The main problem with goto is that some believe that *deprecating* goto makes them look smart.

Comment: @Yai0Phah My characterization of bossy sophomores was not entirely fair. Many of them are just programmers who have taken bad advice. Most will eventually grow out of the prejudice but, yes, goto is just a programming element the need for which seldom arises. The eternal discussion over goto's legitimacy just is not very interesting, once one grasps that the discussion hardly regards any practical point of real programming since 1985. Even *when* goto is less than ideal—well, many programming constructs are less than ideal without being especially bad. Goto is fine.

Comment: What do you mean by you aren't supposed to share your work? I figure you mean the only good example you have is something you did for work but aren't allowed to share; is that correct?

Comment: @flam2006 That's right.  I probably could have shared the code if I had asked but since I was mostly discussing what I thought was wrong with it, I didn't want to go to my supervisor and say "Is it ok if I post some of your code and complain about it?"

Answer (score 5):

Personally I'd refactor it more like this:

```
int DoLotsOfStuffThatCouldFail (paramstruct *params)
{
    int errcode = EC_NOERROR;

    if ((errcode = FunctionThatCouldFail1 (params)) != EC_NOERROR) return errcode;
    if ((errcode = FunctionThatCouldFail2 (params)) != EC_NOERROR) return errcode;
    if ((errcode = FunctionThatCouldFail3 (params)) != EC_NOERROR) return errcode;
    if ((errcode = FunctionThatCouldFail4 (params)) != EC_NOERROR) return errcode;

    return EC_NOERROR;
}

void DoStuff (paramstruct *params)
{
    int errcode = EC_NOERROR;

    InitStuffThatMayNeedToBeCleaned (params);

    if ((errcode = DoLotsOfStuffThatCouldFail (params)) != EC_NOERROR)
    {
         CleanupAfterError (params, errcode);
    }
}
```

That would be more motivated by avoiding the deep nesting than avoiding the goto however (IMO a worse problem with the first code sample), and would of course be dependent on CleanupAfterError being possible out-of-scope (in this case "params" could be a struct containing some allocated memory that you need to free, a FILE * that you need to close or whatever).

One major advantage I see with this approach is that it's both easier and cleaner to slot a hypothetical future extra step between, say, FTCF2 and FTCF3 (or remove an existing current step), so it lends itself better to maintainability (and the person who inherits my code not wanting to lynch me!) - goto aside, the nested version lacks that.

Comment: I didn't state this in my question, but it is possible that the FTCFs do NOT have the same parameters, making this pattern a little more complicated. Thanks though.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the MISRA (Motor Industry Software Reliability Association) C coding guidelines that allow goto under strict criteria (Which your example meets)

Where I work the same code would be written - no goto needed - Avoiding needless religious debate about them is a big plus in any software house.

```
error = function_that_could_fail_1();
if(!error) {
  error = function_that_could_fail_2();
}
if(!error) {
  error = function_that_could_fail_3();
} 
if(!error) {
...
if (error) {
  cleanup:
}
```

or for "goto in drag" - something even more dodgy than goto, but gets around the "No goto Ever!!!" camp) "Surely it must be OK, does not use Goto" ....

```
do {
  if (error = function_that_could_fail_1() ){
    break 
  }
  if (error = function_that_could_fail_2() ){
    break 
  }
  ....... 
} while (0) 
cleanup();
....
```

If the functions have the same parameter type, put them into a table and use a loop -

Comment: The current MISRA-C:2004 guidelines do _not_ allow goto in any form (see rule 14.4). Note the MISRA committee has always been confused about this, they don't know which foot to stand on. First, they unconditionally banned the use of goto, continue etc. But in the draft for the upcoming MISRA 2011 they want to allow them again. As a sidenote, please note that MISRA bans assignment inside if-statements, for very good reasons since it is far more dangerous than any use of goto.

Comment: From an analytical perspective, adding a flag to a program is equivalent to duplicating all the code code where the flag is in scope, having every `if(flag)` in one copy take the "if" branch, and having each corresponding statements in the other copy take the "else".  Actions which set and clear the flag are really "gotos" that jump between those two versions of the code.  There are times when use of flags is cleaner than any alternative, but adding a flag to save one `goto` target is not a good trade-off.

Comment: It not only gets around the “no goto ever” camp, it also gets around the C++ “no goto past uninitialised variable” rule.

Answer (score 1):

I also use `goto` if the alternative `do/while/continue/break` hackery would be *less* readable.

`goto`s have the advantage that their targets have a name and they read `goto something;`. This may be more readable than `break` or `continue` if you're not actually stopping or continuing something.

Comment: Could you give an example where `break` or `continue` do something other than stopping or continuing a loop?

Comment: Anywhere inside a `do ... while(0)` or another construct which isn't an actual loop but a harebrained attempt to prevent the usage of a `goto`.

Comment: Ah, thanks, I didn't know this particular brand of "Why the hell would someone do that?!" constructs yet.

Comment: @BenjaminKloster: `break` is also used to mark the end of cases in a `switch` statement.

Comment: Usually, the do/while/continue/break hackery only becomes unreadable when the module containing it is way too fricking long in the first place.

Comment: I can't find anything in this as a justification to use goto. Break and continue have an obvious consequence. goto...where? Where is the label? Break and goto tell you exactly where the next step is and its nearby.

Comment: The label should of course be visible from within the loop. I agree with the fricking length part of @John R. Strohm's comment.

And your point, translated to loop hackery, becomes "Break out of what? This isn't a loop!". In any case, this is becoming what the OP feared it might, so I'm abandoning the discussion.

Comment: @alb: If you write C++ then do ... while (0) with breaks is not harebrained but necessary. C++ doesn't let you goto over initialisers, so most C gotos just don't compile.

Answer (score -1):

There will always be camps that say one way is acceptable and another that is not. Companies I've worked for have frowned or strongly discouraged goto use. Personally, I can't think of any time I've used one, but that doesn't mean they are *bad*, just another way of doing things.

In C, I typically do the following:

- Test for conditions that could prevent processing (bad inputs, etc) and "return"
- Do all steps that require resource allocation (e.g. mallocs)
- Perform the processing, where multiple steps check for success
- Release any resources, if successfully allocated
- Return any results

For the processing, using your goto example, I'd do this:

error = function_that_could_fail_1();
if(!error) {
    error = function_that_could_fail_2();
}
if(!error) {
    error = function_that_could_fail_3();
}

There no nesting, and inside the if clauses, you can do any error reporting, if the step generated an error. So, it doesn't have to be "worse" than a method using gotos.

I have yet to run across a case where someone has gotos that can't be done with another method and is just as readable/understandable and that is the key, IMHO.

Answer (score -2):

```
for (int y=0; y<height; ++y) {
    for (int x=0; x<width; ++x) {
        if (find(x, y)) goto found;
    }
}
found:
```

Comment: If there's only one loop, `break` works exactly like `goto`, though bearing no stigma.

Comment: -1: First, x and y are OUT OF SCOPE at found:, so this doesn't help you any.  Second, with the code as written, the fact that you arrived at found: does not mean you found what you were looking for.

Comment: It's because this is the smallest example I could think of for the case of breaking out of a multiple number of loops. Please feel free to edit it for a better label or a done check.

Comment: But also bear in mind that C functions are not necessarily side-effect-free.

Comment: @JohnR.Strohm That doesn't make alot of sense... The 'found' label is used to break the loop, not to check the variables. If I wanted to check the variables I could do something like this:
    for (int y=0; y<height; ++y) {
        for (int x=0; x<width; ++x) {
            if (find(x, y)) {
                doSomeThingWith(x,y);
                goto found;
            }
        }
    }
    found:

Comment: Just put the code in its own function, and use a return statement.

Comment: Oh sure, then deal with the *functions should always have a single return* folk rather than the *gotos are always* bad folk. /s